# Select all radio buttons which are checked with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have several input elements which look like this:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="handle[123]" />
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="2" name="handle[456]" />
```

The number inside the name attribute is an object id i need. Now what I want to do is:

1. Fetch all input which are of type="radio" and are checked with prototype
2. Put all ids and values in an associative array

...so the resulting array looks something like this:

```
array{ 1 => 123, 2 => 456 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
var results = [];
document.body.select('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function (element) {
    var object = {};
    object[element.value] = element.name.match(/\d+/)[0];
    results.push(object);
}); 

new Ajax.Request('/some_url', {
  method: 'post',
  parameters: results
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7gtRB/1)

Answer (score 1):

To get the checked radio button given a form id, and the name of the radio group:

```
function RF(el, radioGroup) {
    if($(el).type && $(el).type.toLowerCase() == 'radio') {
        var radioGroup = $(el).name;
        var el = $(el).form;
    } else if ($(el).tagName.toLowerCase() != 'form') {
        return false;
    }

    var checked = $(el).getInputs('radio', radioGroup).find(
        function(re) {return re.checked;}
    );
    return (checked) ? $F(checked) : null;
}

var value = RF('form_id', 'radio_grp_name');
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$$('input:checked[type=radio]').each(function (ele) {
    output[ele.name.match(/\d+/)[0]] = ele.value;
});
```

This would give the desired output using prototype